# iframe width issues with iphone

Tags: iphone, wordpress, iframe

I have a wordpress responsive theme that has twitter, instagram and facebook iframes in widget text boxes.

I have set the iframes to 100% but on the iPhone the facebook and instagram iframes still overflow the over div. I have set the outer div to have overflow: hidden; which helps, but still is not ideal. Thus the issue is that the iframe doesn't resize and the edge is lost.

Here is a link to the site:

http://tinyurl.com/ofsbu8o

What do I need to do to correct this? I have looked around but can't seem to get a working fix.

Regards,
Nate